# How to convert datatype of a column from object to vector of pandas dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, vector, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe which has vectors in a column and its column data type is object, I want to convert its datatype to vector.

```
t["res1"][1]
```

and its output is-

```
[0.350562388776, 0.203056015074, -0.313145598397]
```

And its data type is

```
res1 404290 non-null object
```

And I want its data type as vector. 
I have idea how to do it with spark dataframe but not with pandas dataframe.
Please help

Comment: what do you mean a vector....

Comment: vector is tuple in python. Try `tuple(t["res1"][1])`

Comment: I want **res1 404290 non-null vector** which is datatype of a column which is like **res1 404290 non-null object**  right now. I did this with spark dataframe but have no idea for pandas dataframe.